# RTS Camera: The y and z values seem to be mixed up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I've been trying to figure out how to use the RTS plugin from the unity Asset Store but there seems to be a problem. I have no idea why this is happening, but the z and y values are mixed up. I can scroll left and right perfectly but whenever I press "W" the screen zooms out instead of moving upwards. The same applies to scrolling. When I scroll, the screen moves upwards/downwards and doesn't zoom out like its supposed too. I tried creating my own RTS camera via Brackeys and the same thing happened. His game would zoom, mine would just move upwards. I'm not for sure whats wrong. Im fairly new to all this unity jazz. ANY help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a little hard to know exactly why this is with the information you have provided. But if I were you the first thing I would check is your input manager! Have you done that and made sure your inputs correlate to exactly what you want?

It's sounds like your settings may be not be the default, causing the differences?